# Some Google CDN resources have short expiry dates

Tags: caching, google-analytics, cdn, google-plus-one

I was analysing my page with Google PageSpeed, but was suprised to find that it was Google itself bringing errors:

## Suggestions for this page

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiry of at least one week in the future for the following resources:

- https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (30 minutes)
- http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (12 hours)

It seems Google's CDN files for +1 and Analytics have super-short expiry times, defeating the purpose of a CDN.

Why is this the case?

Comment: The purpose of a CDN is not long expiration times...!

Comment: @deceze Well the purpose of a CDN is to load content faster, and 30 minute expiration dates seem to defeat that purpose

Comment: My guess would be that they want to be able to update those files on a moment's notice, especially for the still relatively new G+ service. Since Google has servers literally all over the globe, with all sorts of distributed DNS tricks to make them even faster, and the files are pretty small, I'd think it's simply fast enough for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a CDN is to *distribute* content, thereby putting it closer to your users and reducing the distance factor of the round trip time (RTT), and doesn't have an impact *per say* on the other two factors of the RTT, namely the speed of light and the time it takes the server to respond to the request.

In the general case, it is often static content, which can *easily* benefit from simple caching rules, that is put on a CDN since most CDNs don't have dynamic content generation capabilities, but there's nothing that says you can't put dynamic (ie. not easily cacheable) content on a CDN.

As far as why Google has elected to have relatively short cache expiry windows, there is always a tradeoff when it comes to *any* performance improvement, particularly with caching. The biggest trade-off for caching is the balance between the-most-recent-content-possible, and the resources it takes to generate the-most-recent-content.

This balance gets dramatically shifted by the scale of users that it impacts, and the resources you have available to spend on generating the content. In Google's case, I would guess that they have decided that a 30-minute window is long enough that they see a *massive* resource benefit, but is still short enough that they are happy with limiting themselves to a 30minute minimum response time for deploying new code.

[Here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/caching-fun-and-profit-or-why) is an interesting look at why caching things for even 5 seconds can be a worthwhile proposition, though you have to balance that with the update window, and I mentioned before.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer. I guess deploying new code quickly would be important for security fixes etc.